# How to fill in map inside target object by copying values from source object using -MapStruct?

Tags: java, mapstruct, dto-mapping

I am new to Mapstruct. I have a scenario where, in my target object I have a java map with key value pair<String,String> and I have to fill this map using source objects inner object properties/data member values.

My code is something like bellow(dummy code):

```
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public String rollNo;
    public Map<String, String> marks;
}


public class ExamResult{

    public String stud_name;
    public String Stud_rollNo;
    public Marks marks;
}

public class Marks{
    public Integer English;
    public Integer Maths;
    public Integer Science;
}
```

How would I manually achieve the same thing like bellow:

```
Student target;
ExamResult source;
target.setName(source.stud_name);
target.setRollNo(source.Stud_RollNo);
target.marks.put("ENGLISH",source.marks.english_marks);
target.marks.put("MATHS",source.marks.math_marks);
target.marks.put("SCIENCE",source.marks.science_marks);
```

For direct property mapping I have found code, but not sure how I can map the values to be filled in the `marks` map.

I had given a thought to use java expression to fill in target map values, but didn't found any documentation or such example of expressions using for target object.

I was thinking to use like bellow but not sure it will work:

```
    @Mapping(source = "stud_name", target = "name")
    @Mapping(source = "Stud_RollNo", target = "rollNo")
    @Mapping(source = "source.marks.english_marks",target = "java( marks.put(\"ENGLISH\",source.marks.english_marks )")
    @Mapping(source = "source.marks.math_marks",target = "java( marks.put(\"MATHS\",source.marks.math_marks )")
    @Mapping(source = "source.marks.science_marks",target = "java( marks.put(\"SCIENCE\",source.marks.science_marks )")
Student doConvert(ExamResult src)
```

Any help, any suggestion or any workaround is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7):

Using expressions in `target` is not allowed for MapStruct, that's why you couldn't make it work.

Mapping into maps from objects is also not supported yet, we have different issues requesting this feature.

What I would suggest is to use the automatic mapping as much as possible when you can and then resort to `@AfterMapping` when MapStruct can't do that. So in your case something like:

```
@Mapper
public interface StudentMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "stud_name", target = "name")
    @Mapping(source = "Stud_RollNo", target = "rollNo")
    @Mapping(target = "marks", ignore = true) // mapped in @AfterMapping
    Student doConvert(ExamResult src)

    @AfterMapping
    default void addStudentMarks(ExamResult result, @MappingTarget Student student) {
        student.marks = new HashMap<>();
        student.marks.put("ENGLISH", result.marks.ENGLISH);
        student.marks.put("MATHS", result.marks.MATHS);
        student.marks.put("SCIENCE", result.marks.SCIENCE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a Custom mapper method to convert the Marks into Map Object

```
@Mapping(source = "stud_name", target = "name")
@Mapping(source = "Stud_rollNo", target = "rollNo")
Student doConvert(ExamResult examResult);

static Map<String,String> mapMarks(Marks marks) {
    Map<String,String> marksMap = new HashMap<>();
    marksMap.put("ENGLISH", String.valueOf(marks.getEnglish()));
    marksMap.put("MATHS", String.valueOf(marks.getMaths()));
    return marksMap;
}
```

In case the map elements are too big to mention, Jackson Library could be used which can dynamically create the map with reference name as Key and Object value as value

```
@Mapping(source = "stud_name", target = "name")
@Mapping(source = "Stud_rollNo", target = "rollNo")
Student doConvert(ExamResult examResult);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
static Map<String,String> mapMarks(Marks marks) {
    return mapper.convertValue(marks, Map.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping( target = "name", source = "stud_name")
    @Mapping( target = "rollNo", source = "stud_rollNo")
    // marks will be mapped based on name equality
    Student map( ExamResult result);

    // mapstruct sees an unmapped property (although it only has a getter), marks
    @Mapping( target = "marks", ignore = true )
    MarksWrapper toWrapper(Marks marks );

    // handwritten method, just to do the mapping
    default Map<String, Integer> toMap( MarksWrapper wrapper) {
        return wrapper.getMarks();
    }

    // this class does the conversion
    class MarksWrapper {

        private Map<String, Integer> marks = new HashMap<>(  );

        public void setEnglish( Integer mark) {
            marks.put( "ENGLISH", mark );
        }
        public void setMaths( Integer mark ){
            marks.put( "MATH", mark );
        }
        public void setScience( Integer mark ) {
            marks.put( "SCIENCE", mark );
        }
        public Map<String, Integer> getMarks() {
            return marks;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I used a `Map<String,Integer>` `Map<String,String>` but the idea is the same..